# Can not assign final fields with builder pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a DTO following the builder pattern, but I have an error.

**The question:**

> The final field SearchRequestDTO.requestType cannot be assigned
>
> The final field SearchRequestDTO.requestSubType cannot be assigned

Why am getting the following error in the private constructor of SearchRequestDTO:

**The code:**

```
public class SearchRequestDTO {

   private final String requestType = null;
   private final String requestSubType = null;

    private SearchRequestDTO(SearchRequestDTOBuilder builder){
        this.requestType = builder.requestType ;
        this.requestSubType = builder.requestSubType;
    }

    public String getRequestType() {
        return requestType;
    }

    public String getRequestSubType() {
        return requestSubType;
    }

    public static class SearchRequestDTOBuilder {
        private String requestType = null;
        private String requestSubType = null;

        public SearchRequestDTOBuilder requestType(String requestType){
            this.requestType = requestType;
            return this;
        }
        public SearchRequestDTOBuilder requestSubType(String requestSubType){
            this.requestSubType = requestSubType;
            return this;
        }

        public SearchRequestDTO build(){
            return new SearchRequestDTO(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you assigned it the value `null` when you declared it. You can't assign it twice.

Comment: I have no problems with your code, except one - you have no pageNumber field.

Comment: @OrestSavchak, sorry for that, the right code it is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is obvious.

```
   private final String requestType;
   private final String requestSubType;

    private SearchRequestDTO(SearchRequestDTOBuilder builder){
        this.requestType = builder.requestType ;
        this.requestSubType = builder.requestSubType ;
    }

    public String getRequestType() {
        return requestType;
    }

    public String getRequestSubType() {
        return requestSubType;
    }
```

If you want to have final field, you have to initialize it at least and only once. If you init it before - you will have an compile error. If you don't init it - tou will have an compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable final ,that's why you cannot override it. You can only assign it value during declaration.

Comment: You're not forced to assign a `final` field at declaration time - you're forced to assign it by the time to constructor completes.